# How can I find the state of a button from its value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have written JavaScript which changes the value of the buttons when clicked. For example, the value of button changes from “Ignore Select” to “Enable Select” on click.

My problem is how to find the state of the buttons as enabled or disabled using the value of the buttons. I tried to store element value in an array (var a[]="select";). but the button stops changing color which I have already done.Is there any other way to store the value of buttons in array??

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="button" name="Ignore Select" value="Ignore Select" id="select" onclick="colorchange('select')" style="background:rgb(255,145,0);"/>
<input type="button" name="Ignore Delete" value="Ignore Delete" id="select1" onclick="colorchange('select1');" style="background:rgb(255,145,0);"/>
<input type="button" name="Ignore Insert" value="Ignore Insert" id="select2" onclick="colorchange('select2');" style="background:rgb(255,145,0);"/>
<input type="button" name="Ignore Update" value="Ignore Update" id="select3" onclick="colorchange('select3');" style="background:rgb(255,145,0);"/>
<input type="button" name="Ignore Sleep" value="Ignore Sleep" id="select4" onclick="colorchange('select4');" style="background:rgb(255,145,0);"/>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
<script>
function colorchange(id) 
{
   var elem = document.getElementById(id);
if(id=="select")
 { 
  if (elem.value=="Ignore Select") 
  {
   elem.value = "Enable Select";
   var a[]="select";
  }
  else
  { 
   elem.value = "Ignore Select"; 
  }
 }

if(id=="select1")
{
 if (elem.value=="Ignore Delete") 
 {
   elem.value = "Enable Delete";
   var a[]="delete";
 }
 else
 { 
  elem.value = "Ignore Delete";
 }
}

if(id=="select2")
{
 if (elem.value=="Ignore Insert")
 {
   elem.value = "Enable Insert";
  var a[]="insert";
 }
 else
 {
  elem.value = "Ignore Insert";
 }
}

if(id=="select3")
{
 if (elem.value=="Ignore Update")
 {
   elem.value = "Enable Update";
   var a[]="update";
 }
 else
 {
  elem.value = "Ignore Update";
 }
}

if(id=="select4")
{
 if (elem.value=="Ignore Sleep")
 {
   elem.value = "Enable Sleep";
   var a[]="sleep";
 }
 else
 {
  elem.value = "Ignore Sleep";
 }
}
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the disabled property? Maybe document.getElementById(id).disabled this would return true or false..  try also using a `switch(id)`

Comment: Paul, what are you trying to do? It seems like you are already checking "the sate" of the button using its current value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of the button with val() function
Example
$("input:button[name='Ignore Select']").val()

Comment: @Surhabi: No, he can't since he's not using jquery. Also, he's already getting the value using elem.value...

Comment: yes, I am already getting the value using "elem.value" , so that how can I store the value of "elem.value" in a variable array?? How can I modify my code to store value of "elem.value" in a variable array using javascript?